# PT algorithm for ML type inference

Tags: type-inference, ml, bound-variable

For the PT algorithm for ML type inference to work, the input program expression has to have the property that every bound variable is distinct. Can somebody explain it with an example?

Comment: Can anyone share a link to this PT algorithm? I'm not aware of any and Google points back to this question.

Comment: What makes you think that that is a requirement? AFAICT, algorithm W can deal with scoping and shadowing just fine. What has to be uniquely chosen ("fresh") are the inference type variables.

Comment: If "PT" is referring to *principal type*, that's a property of the type system, not an algorithm, but the Hindley-Milner algorithm uses a unification algorithm to compute the principal type. Could you explain what exactly you're wondering, and what you mean by "every bound variable is distinct"?

Comment: PT is referring to principle type and the given algorithm is Hindley-Milner. In other words, is renaming necessary for pure λ-expression? (let-free expressions)

Answer (score 0):

The point is simply that variables bound by different binders are different from each other, and hence may have different types. So, it is a good practice to rename them, in order to avoid confusion and to be able to talk about the type of "x", without having to worry about which among the binders of "x" we are referring to.